# ACL for custom config group - section disppeared?

Tags: system-config, acl, magento2.2.6

I'v tried to add a new section to `Store -> Config -> Catalog Section -> Catalog` with custom ACL settings.

I changed (default) adminrole permissions from "All" to "Custom" and left only the new option unchecked.

**Expected:**

- new group does not appear

**Result:**

- whole `Catalog Section` disappears

---

system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
  <system>
    <section id="catalog">
      <resource>StackExchange_LockAttributes::configuration</resource>
      <group id="backend" translate="label" sortOrder="9999" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Product Attribute Settings</label>
        <field id="lock_attributes" translate="label tooltip comment" sortOrder="10" type="multiselect" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
          <label>Locked Attributes</label>
          <comment>Product attributes that can't be edited.</comment>
          <source_model>StackExchange\LockAttributes\Model\System\Config\Source\Product\Attributes\Frontend</source_model>
          <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
        </field>
      </group>
    </section>
  </system>
</config>
```

acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
  <resources>
    <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
      <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
          <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
            <resource id="Magento_Catalog::config_catalog">
              <resource id="StackExchange_LockAttributes::configuration" title="Edit Locked Attributes Section" translate="title" sortOrder="100"/>
            </resource>
          </resource>
        </resource>
      </resource>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

helper ...

```
public function isAllowed()
{
    return $this->authorization->isAllowed('StackExchange_LockAttributes::configuration');
}
```

---

Extension works ... only config section makes trouble.

What's wrong with my code?

---

Btw ... i've played arround with `CatalogSearch` ACL role and it seems it has no effect at all. If I uncheck ACL role, system config for CatalogSearch should not be visiable, but it's still there,

Answer (score 0):

In `system.xml` you have set the resource for the section, not for the group. So you have overridden the default acl resource with your own. However, IMHO it is unfortunately not possible out of the box to set an acl resource on a group scope level.